# Variational AutoEncoder - TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement a VAE for MNIST using convolutional layers using TensorFlow-2.6 and Python-3.9. The code I have is:

```
# Specify latent space dimensions-
latent_space_dim = 3

# Define encoder-
encoder_input = Input(shape = (28, 28, 1))

x = Conv2D(
    filters = 32, kernel_size = 3,
    strides = 2, padding = 'same')(encoder_input)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2D(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = 3,
    strides = 2, padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2D(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = 3,
    strides = 1, padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2D(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = 3,
    strides = 1, padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

shape_before_flattening = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
x = Flatten()(x)

# Instead of connecting the flattened layer directly to the 3-D latent space, we connect
# it to layers 'mu' and 'log_var'-
mu = Dense(units = latent_space_dim)(x)
log_var = Dense(units = latent_space_dim)(x)

# The Keras model that outputs the values of 'mu' & 'log_var' for a given input image-
encoder_mu_log = Model(encoder_input, (mu, log_var))

print(f"shape_before_flattening: {shape_before_flattening}")
# shape_before_flattening: (7, 7, 64)

def sampling(args):
    mu, log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape = K.shape(mu), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0)
    return mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon

# This Lambda layer samples a point 'z' in the latent space from the normal distribution
# defined by the parameters 'mu' and 'log_var'-
encoder_output = Lambda(sampling)([mu, log_var])

# The Keras model that defines the encoder — a model that takes an input image and encodes it
# into the 2D latent space, by sampling a point from the multivariate normal distribution
# defined by 'mu' and 'log_var'-
encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoder_output)

decoder_input = Input(shape = (latent_space_dim))

x = Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flattening))(decoder_input)
x = Reshape(shape_before_flattening)(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(
    filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(
    filters = 1, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same')(x)
x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

decoder_output = x

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output)

# The complete autoencoder-

# The input to the autoencoder is the same as the input to the encoder.
model_input = encoder_input

# The output from the autoencoder is the output from the encoder passed through
# the decoder.
model_output = decoder(encoder_output)

# The Keras model that defines the full autoencoder—a model that takes an image,
# and passes it through the encoder and back out through the decoder to generate
# a reconstruction of the original image.
model = Model(model_input, model_output)
```

The loss function is defined as follows:

```
# Weight the reconstruction loss 'r_loss_factor' to ensure that it is well balanced with the KL divergence loss-
r_loss_factor = 1000

def vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Reconstruction loss-
    r_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis = [1,2,3])
    return r_loss_factor * r_loss

def vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # KL-Divergence loss-
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis = 1)
    return kl_loss

def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # VAE loss = Reconstruction loss + KL-Divergence loss
    r_loss = vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    kl_loss = vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    return r_loss + kl_loss

# Compile model-
model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.003),
    loss = vae_loss,
    metrics = [vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss]
)

# Train autoencoder-
training_hist = model.fit(
    x = X_train, y = X_train,
    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True,
    validation_data = (X_test, X_test),
    epochs = num_epochs
    )
```

which gives the error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11960/995477119.py in 
> 1 # Train autoencoder-
> ----> 2 training_hist = model.fit(
> 3     x = X_train, y = X_train,
> 4     batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True,
> 5     validation_data = (X_test, X_test),
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,
> use_multiprocessing)    1191                 _r=1):    1192
> callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1193               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)    1194               if data_handler.should_sync:    1195
> context.async_wait()
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 883
> 884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
> --> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 886
> 887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 931       # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
> 932       initializers = []
> --> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
> 934     finally:
> 935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
> 757     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
> 758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
> --> 759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>
> ## pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ```
> 760             *args, **kwds))
> 761
> ```
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
> **kwargs)    3064       args, kwargs = None, None    3065     with self._lock:
> -> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    3067     return graph_function    3068
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    3461     3462
> self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
> -> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
> graph_function    3465
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)    3296     arg_names = base_arg_names +
> missing_arg_names    3297     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
> -> 3298         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(    3299             self._name,    3300             self._python_function,
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
> in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
> func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
> arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
> override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)    1005
> _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)    1006
> -> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)    1008     1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors,
> CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
> 667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
> --> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> 669         return out
> 670
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
> 993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> --> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> 995             else:
> 996               raise
>
> TypeError: in user code:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:862
> ```
>
> train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:852
> step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286
> run
> return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849
> call_for_each_replica
> return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632
> _call_for_each_replica
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845
> run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:803
> train_step
> loss = self.compiled_loss(
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:242
> **call**
> self._loss_metric.update_state(
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:88
> decorated
> update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:171
> update_state_fn
> return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:403
> update_state  **
> sample_weight = weights_broadcast_ops.broadcast_weights(
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\weights_broadcast_ops.py:157
> broadcast_weights
> values = ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name="values")
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py:163
> wrapped
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1566
> convert_to_tensor
> ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:346
> _constant_tensor_conversion_function
> return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:271
> constant
> return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:288
> _constant_impl
> tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py:435
> make_tensor_proto
> values = np.asarray(values)
> C:\Users\Arjun\anaconda3\envs\tf-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py:254
> **array**
> raise TypeError(
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic
> ```
>
> value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying
> to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not
> register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting
> the API call to a lambda layer in the F

unctional Model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add loss and metrics as below.

```
# Add reconstruction loss
r_loss = r_loss_factor * (K.mean(K.square(model_input - model_output), axis = [1,2,3])) # no need of r_loss_factor, better to remove it, instead use kl_beta in KL loss formula
model.add_loss(r_loss)
model.add_metric(r_loss, name='mse_loss', aggregation='mean')

# Add KL loss
kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis = 1)
# below formula will give you more accurate result
# kl_loss = kl_beta * K.mean(-0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis = 1), axis=0) # read more on KL annealing technique to understand how kl_beta will be scaled during the whole traning
model.add_loss(kl_loss)
model.add_metric(kl_loss, name='kl_loss', aggregation='mean')

# Compile model-
model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.003),
    loss = None
)
```